# how to save json data nsuserdefault and use it next view controller Swift 3.0?

Tags: json, xcode, drop-down-menu, save, nsuserdefaults

```
if let con  = country [ "country_id"] as? Int{
        print("++++++ \(con ) ++++")

        self.countryidID.append(con)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.countryidID, forKey: "Key")
                print(self.countryidID)
```

I create two type of dropdown (country, city) when I click "country" button then passed "city-ID" and show dropdown list selected country cities.

My problem is that I'm not saving my city id data and can't retrieve it. I'm not able to correctly save the data object to userDefaults and retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

Save a string with `UserDefaults.standard.set("random_strong", forKey: "object_string")`

Save with `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` to save immediatly

Retrieve with `var variable = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "object")`